# Making a chat room with Facebook authentication

Tags: facebook, xmpp, facebook-chat

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to create an embeddable online chat room that requires a Facebook authentication. I want the chat room to be public, allow users to log in with their Facebook accounts, and chat with each other using their Facebook identity(name). I know how to authenticate users into a website using FBML and FQL, but I don't know how to incorporate that concept in creating a chat room. Facebook Chat uses XMPP, so I looked up XMPP multi chat documentation, but I can't understand really well. I can do PHP and JavaScript(jQuery/JSON/etc). Can someone help me how to go about making such a chat room?

Comment: This would most likely be best asked @ http://stackoverflow.com

Comment: This is a very broad question. I would recommend breaking this up into a more specific question such as what XMPP library to use, etc. This is going to be a very complicated application with many parts.

Answer (score 1):

Building such a thing will not be possible until unless you hack your way around this. Not possible mainly because facebook still lacks federation i.e. as soon as fb chat servers sees -123456@chat.facebook.com trying to send a message of type "groupchat" to a MUC room jdev@conference.jabber.org, it will block this message stanza and not pass it on to the MUC room.

Hacking such a thing will involve writing your custom Jabber/XMPP components running at your own chat servers, which will then take care of outgoing messages of type "groupchat" from your system and re-route them appropriately to the MUC rooms. [Jaxl IM](http://jaxl.im) is a project which does exactly the same thing and it uses [Jaxl (Jabber XMPP Library in PHP)](http://jaxl.net) library for all such purposes.